# Django Elastic Search configuration for modeltranslation fields

Tags: django, elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch with Django.

I've a model "Product", that has title field. I'm also using django-modeltranslation for my Product model to translate title field in several languages.

How can I return title field matches with language that coming from request in Elastic Search. I've ElasticSearch currently working, but it's returning default title field